# Hashing a string between two integers with a good distribution (Uniform Hash)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash

I'm trying to hash some strings between 0 and a very low n in order to give one color per user.

Here is my (working) code:

```
 function nameToColor(name) {
            var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'darkred', 'darkblue', 'darkgreen', 'cadetblue', 'darkpurple'];
            var hash = hashStr(name);
            var index = hash % colors.length;
            return colors[index];
        }

        //djb2 hash
        function hashStr(str) {
            var hash = 5381;
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + charCode; /* hash * 33 + c */
            }
            return hash;    
        }
```

Unfortunately the low numbers are massively over-represented.

**Question:**

How can I write a deterministic javascript function that takes any string as argument and returns with a good (as uniform as possible) distribution a number between 0 and n?

Comment: Hashing is well understood and way out of scope of this question.  Maybe just use one of the gazillion hash functions that already exist.

Comment: Also Benford's law deals with leading digits (the leftmost) you aren't using the leading digit, you are using the modulus of the hash result.

Comment: @Hogan I'm already using a standard hashing function, it just doesn't fit what I need. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: There are 4 or 5 listed on that page.  I'm guessing you are just seeing results that don't look random enough.  The problem with random is it never looks random.  Random just is.

Comment: @Hogan It isn't a duplicate. I already have a hash function, it's in the code I posted.

Comment: A "deterministic javascript function that takes any string as argument and returns with a good distribution a number between 0 and n" is a hashing function.  This is the definition of a hashing function.  You are asking how to write a good hashing function, that question is the same.

Comment: Here is another link for you http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-

Comment: and another http://werxltd.com/wp/2010/05/13/javascript-implementation-of-javas-string-hashcode-method/

Comment: @the last hash in your link actually fit my needs, thx.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I already tried the JAVA hash, I had the same problem.

Comment: This question was not a duplicate.  He clearly asks for a *uniform* hash function.  The other question does not specify this criterion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hogan gave in comment a [link](http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-) to several hash implementation in javascript. It turns out that the most simple is the most appropriate:

```
function nameToColor(name) {
                var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'darkred', 'darkblue', 'darkgreen', 'cadetblue', 'darkpurple'];
                var hash = hashStr(name);
                var index = hash % colors.length;
                return colors[index];
        }

        //very simple hash
        function hashStr(str) {
            var hash = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
                hash += charCode;
            }
            return hash;
        }
```

I think it works well because it only uses the addition  (no shift or multiplications) which leave the modulo unchanged, so the initial quality of distribution is conserved.

I also found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Variable_range) on wikipedia, but did not have to use it:

> In many applications, the range of hash values may be different for each run of the program, or may change along the same run (for instance, when a hash table needs to be expanded). In those situations, one needs a hash function which takes two parameters—the input data z, and the number n of allowed hash values.
>
> A common solution is to compute a fixed hash function with a very
>   large range (say, 0 to 232 − 1), divide the result by n, and use the
>   division's remainder. If n is itself a power of 2, this can be done by
>   bit masking and bit shifting. When this approach is used, the hash
>   function must be chosen so that the result has fairly uniform
>   distribution between 0 and n − 1, for any value of n that may occur in
>   the application. Depending on the function, the remainder may be
>   uniform only for certain values of n, e.g. odd or prime numbers.
>
> We can allow the table size n to not be a power of 2 and still not
>   have to perform any remainder or division operation, as these
>   computations are sometimes costly. For example, let n be significantly
>   less than 2b. Consider a pseudo random number generator (PRNG)
>   function P(key) that is uniform on the interval [0, 2b − 1]. A hash
>   function uniform on the interval [0, n-1] is n P(key)/2b. We can
>   replace the division by a (possibly faster) right bit shift: nP(key)>> b.

Comment: all hash functions have collisions, but the above one has ones that are quite bad for natural text text:
"ab" and "ba" will have exactly the same hashcode because the used formula is only a sum that does not care about order.
Also: "aaaaaaaaab" and "aaaaaaaaac" will end up having a nearly identical color.

Answer (score 1):

The following hash function, by Brian White, is very generic, use any kind of input (including strings), comes with simple examples, and is written for Javascript node.js.

https://npmjs.org/package/xxhash

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the code above:

```
function hashValue(theString,size){
  var sum = 0;
  for(i=0;i<theString.length;i++){
    sum += theString[i].charCodeAt(0) * 3;
  }
  return sum % size;
}
```

Simply pass a string and the size you want it to have, for example, 36 if you want it to return numbers 0 through 36.  The * 3 can add variation but can be whatever number you want.  I repurposed this idea from here ([Hash function that can return a integer range based on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809770/hash-function-that-can-return-a-integer-range-based-on-string)) by M_callens

Comment: Adding a `* 3` here is mathematically unsound - for example, if `size` is any multiple of 3, everything is going to hash into just 1/3rd of the buckets!